# logcat error in android studio of onCreateView

Tags: android

there is an error being shown in the logcat of android studio while running this code

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,  ViewGroup container,
                        @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

 View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentlayout,container,false);
 return v;
```

can somebody please help me to resolve it . the error is being shown to be in
View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentlayout,container,false);

Comment: what error is shown in logcat?

Comment: Please don't repeat questions. Simply editing your original post with any new information you have, any new code you've tried, or an explanation of why any posted answers aren't working, will bump it to the top of the active queue.